# Does the kobold player race feature, Pack Tactics, give ranged attacks advantage?

Tags: dnd-5e, ranged-attack, racial-traits, advantage-and-disadvantage, kobold

On page 119 of VGtM, the description of the [Kobold playable race's trait](https://www.dndbeyond.com/characters/races/kobold#KoboldTraits), Pack Tactics, reads:

> ***Pack Tactics.*** You have advantage on an attack roll against a creature if at least one of your allies is within 5 feet of the creature and the ally isn't incapacitated.

It doesn't specify whether your attack has to be melee or that the ally must be within 5 feet of your PC.

Does the kobold player race feature, Pack Tactics, give ranged spell and weapon attacks advantage?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

### Your reasoning is correct

Indeed, Pack Tactics only requires that you have an ally within 5 feet of the target so this would work with any attack, including ranged spell or weapon attacks.

If the feature only worked for melee attacks it would say so, but it doesn't, so any attack works.

Answer (score 0):

## That would work

For starters, congrats on ingenuity. In most cases, in games I have played and GMed, my players never really considered that, and neither did I. But when you think about it, it would make sense.

The text from VGtM does not explicitly state otherwise; in fact, it only states that as long as you are attacking a creature and you have an ally within 5 feet of it, you have advantage.

The only way I see this going bad is if you critical fail and your arrow goes slightly off target, only to target your ally... Just don't try to throw a fireball at some creature while your ally stands right there. That would be messy.

Comment: Welcome to RPG.SE! Note that there's no such official thing as a "critical fail"; a [nat. 1 on an attack roll is just a miss](https://www.dndbeyond.com/compendium/rules/basic-rules/combat#Rolling1or20) by RAW, nothing more.

Comment: My bad, I am rather used to the homebrew take I usually spin on it with the approval of the people I play with.

Comment: Fireballs are AOE anyway and that features does not apply since there is no attack roll

Comment: @HussinBinYusof Either way, it would be messy. The fireball does not discriminate when it explodes.